# Paste content of clipboard into URL for Bookmarklet

Tags: javascript, bookmarklet

Hi I currently have the following Bookmarklet:

javascript:

```
(function() { 
    var val= prompt("Enter #",""); 
    if (val) 
        location="https://www.test.com/send?phone="+escape(val);
})()
```

However, instead of pasting a phone number into the dialog box I would like to modify it.

So it would take a phone number with country code ie 
+1708999999

and paste it into the URL (without the + sign)

https://www.test.com/send?phone=1708999999

Could anyone shed some light on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try 
`window.location = "..."`
instead of 
`location = "..."`